# Utilizar una variable como parte de un rango en VB

Tags: excel, vba, vb

Quiero hacer un rango en Visual Basic para crear una macro en exel.

Primero quiero guardar en una variable la celda en la que termina mi columna activa.

```
PDX = Range("E4").End(xlDown).Row
```

Pero esto solo me guarda el numero de celda en el que termina la columna. En mi caso 77, pero necesito guardarla como E77 para utilizarla en un rango parecido a esto

```
Range("E4" & PDX)
```

Quiero hacer esto para copiar un codigo de IF

```
=IF(RC[-2]=RC[-1],""Son iguales"",""No son iguales"")
```

Y que no se pegue hasta la ultima celda de todo el Excel como se ve en esta imagen:

[image: Imagen de referencia]

Quiero que el codigo IF no pase de la celda E77 en este caso, pero que sea guardado como variable para que pueda ser utilizado sin importar lo largo de la lista.

No se si tengan alguna idea de como afrontar este problema.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Para que simplifiques tu caso pasa tus valores a un formato de tabla, luego puedes leer los valores de la primera columna con `worksheets("nombre_de_hoja").ListObjects("nombre_de_tabla").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange` y del mismo modo con la segunda columna. Por ultimo realiza un bucle `for loop` con la condición `if`.

Answer (score 0):

`Range("E4").End(xlDown)` a secas es una referencia directa a la última celda (E77 en tu caso). Si lo que quieres es extraer las coordenadas, puedes usar la propiedad `Address`

> [Propiedad Range.Address
> (Excel)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/excel.range.address)

Algo así debería servirte:

`PDX = Range("E4").End(xlDown).Address(False,False)` para almacenar en `PDX` el valor `E77`